# Use CSS to move cursor to another element

Tags: css, position, cursor

I'm trying to move the location of the cursor (mouse pointer) when an element is brought into view.
Let's say I have a button at the top of screen that, on click, opens a  somewhere else on the screen. They are not connected in the doc flow (the  is position: fixed>

When I show the new item, I want the mouse cursor to move to the newly displayed element, e.g. to the close button inside of it. I added a call to focus() but not working...

```
function myClick(idName) {
  let listOfBios = document.getElementsByClassName("contents");
  const len = listOfBios.length;
  let elemName = "Content_" + idName; 
  let elem = document.getElementById(elemName);
  elem.focus();
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let theBio = listOfBios[i];

    if(theBio != elem){
      //alert(elemName);
      theBio.classList.remove("show_contents")
    }
  }
  elem.classList.toggle("show_contents", 1);
  elem.focus();
}
```

Assume that the rest of the code works, so I definitely have the right element ad toggle() is working.

Comment: CSS can only **style** the *look* of a cursor. Yes, you need Javascript.

Comment: Thx for reminding me. Layout is not code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need JS to achieve this. See below for example with vanilla JS.

in your view:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextField" value="Text field.">
```

in JS:

```
document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
```

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jz7v53tL/

Comment: focus() seems like it might work for an input field, which I don't have in my content, but I feel a hack coming on....maybe an invisible <input>?

Comment: check the fiddle I just added to the answer

Comment: Yah, this changes the input location fine, but I'm trying t change the *pointer* position. Thanks though.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood. It is impossible to force the user's mouse to move around with code. Imagine what you could do with that type of power and it's probably for the best in terms of UX.

Comment: Well, it isn't impossible. I could write a native process in my target OS and do a mouse move from there, but that's way out of scope for this.

Comment: Besides, apps like Selenium hook into browsers for stuff like this. I'm sure there's some webdriver thing I could do as well, but yeah, I'm seeing this is a fail with CSS and JS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't be done with just CSS and JS. Trying to close this out, I hope this is how.